# Search Form in Django with python

Tags: python, django, forms, web

I'm trying to add a simple search form on my django website. When I hit the search button I'm redirected to the new_search.html page (as it should be) but the page doesn't show any result.
Thanks for your help!

The code is this:

I've got an homepage where I put the search form like this:

```
<form method="get" action="{% url 'new_search' %}">
      {%csrf_token%}
      <input type="text" name="srh" class= "form-control" placeholder="Search">
      <button type="submit" name="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

When a user search for something the result should be showed in the new_search.html page.
The function I wrote in the views.py is this:

```
def new_search(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        srch = request.GET.get('srh')

        if srch:
            sr = Info.objects.filter(Q(band__icontains=srch) | Q(disco__icontains=srch))

            if sr:
                return render(request, 'new_search.html', {'sr':sr})
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'no results')
        else:
            return render(request, 'new_search')

    return render(request, 'new_search.html')
```

And the new_search.html page is this:

```
    <div>
{% if sr %}
  {% for k in sr %}
        <table width="200px">
          <tr><td>Band</td><td>{{k.band}}</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Album</td><td>{{k.disco}}</td></tr>
        </table>
  {%endfor%}
{%endif%}
    </div>
```

The model.py is this:

```
class Info(models.Model):
    band = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Write Here")
    disco = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Write Here")
    etichetta_p = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Write Here")
    etichetta_d = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Write Here")
    matrice = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Write Here")
    anno = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.band
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('search.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

app urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', homeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('anno', views.anno, name='anno'),
    path('band/', bandView.as_view(), name='band'),
    path('album/', albumView.as_view(), name='album'),
    path('add/create', views.AddInfo.as_view(), name='add_create'),
    path('signup/', core_views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('new_search/', new_searchView.as_view(), name='new_search'),
]
```

Comment: Why are you using `GET` method in your form?

Comment: because it gave me an error with POST but i'm going to fix it and use POST method @errata

Comment: Do you have any errors in logs? Can you post them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you should handle `POST` method in your class view, since you're using one, for example:

```py
class new_searchView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "new_search.html"

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('FORM POSTED WITH {}'.format(request.POST['srh']))
        return render(self.request, 'new_search.html')
```

Comment: I keep having a 405 error with POST method. @errata

Comment: That means you have a different problem then... Search the web what 405 HTTP error is, it looks like you are not allowing the POST method on that endpoint...

Comment: I think i'm missing something in new_search(request), maybe with the redirect urls

Comment: Should I add something in the urls.py?? @errata

Comment: Yes, you probably have to allow POST method for that path!

Comment: what should be the syntax? @errata

Comment: Can you update your original post with `urls.py` and settings?

Comment: Updated it @errata

Comment: Updated my answer!

Comment: Thanks now it works properly! I'm still confused about what I did wrong, but thanks!

Comment: Glad I helped, feel free to accept the answer! I beleive (didn’t work with Django for some time) that you simply needed to define post() method in your class view since it’s not “enabled” by default...